# How to make a hashmap that contains SomeType<K,V>?

Tags: java, jpa, dao

```
map = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<K,V>>, AbstractDAO<K,V>>);
```

is not allowed

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: You need what are `K` and `V`. Did you declare them in your class?

Comment: no because they are variable.. i cannot use specific type for K and V since the DAOs that extend this abstract class can be of type AbstractDAO<Entity1,Integer> , AbstractDAO < Entity2, Integer> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like following :

```
 class Test<K, V> {
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<K,V>>, AbstractDAO<K,V>>();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, as long as you declare `K` and `V` as types.

Here I've declared them as *method* types:

```
public static class AbstractDAO<K, V> {
}

public static <K, V> void typedMethod() {
    Map<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<K, V>>, AbstractDAO<K, V>> map 
      = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<K, V>>, AbstractDAO<K, V>>();
}
```

Or if you don't want to declare the types, leave everything "unknown" with wildcards everywhere:

```
public static void method() {
    Map<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<?, ?>>, AbstractDAO<?, ?>> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractDAO<?, ?>>, AbstractDAO<?, ?>>();
}
```

All of the above code compiles.